# Getting a 403 error after upgrading to php5.5

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2, upgrade, chmod

OK I am new to ASKING questions on stackoverflow, but I need to get this figured out. I have a VPS with Apache installed Running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I downloaded a php script which required php 5.4+ but I had 5.3 installed. Then I followed the instructions located at [this link.](https://serverfault.com/questions/420286/how-do-i-upgrade-from-php-5-3-to-php-5-4-6-in-ubuntu)
While doing the upgrade, the installer told me that my php.ini file was manually changed. I believe I did this in order to view the errors on screen with the **"display_errors=on"** variable a long time ago. I therefore selected the option to KEEP and USE the old version of php.ini. Once the installation was done and the apache server restarted. I went to my chrome browser and pressed **"refresh"** and to my dismay, **"403 Forbidden"**.

Here is the conf file for the virtual server:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /home/{usr}/Public/
    # Indexes + Directory Root.
    DirectoryIndex  index.html index.shtml index.php
    <Directory />
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/{usr}/Public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /home/{usr}/Public/log/{server}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /home/{usr}/Public/log/{server}/access.log combined

     Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I obscured the username to {usr} and the folder to {server} to keep anonymity. This file was created BY ME, by putting it together with some other example file. I'm not sure if this is correct, all I know is that before this upgrade, everything was working fine!

I also **"LL"**'d the **"Public"** folder and here's what I found:

```
drwxrwxrwx 28 {usr} {usr}   4096 Sep  4 01:09 Public/
```

It seems that all the folders under it have the same permission. Please help and if there are any questions, feel free to ask. I've been doing this for many years but by no means would I call myself an "expert".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you also upgrade Apache 2 ?
Apache 2.4 has a new user rights policy system : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#run-time

Comment: I am running **Apache 2.4.6** currently.

Comment: In Apache 2.4.x, 
"Order allow,deny
Allow from all"
doesn't exist anymore. It's been replaced by :
Require all granted

Comment: OK I replaced the .conf files as you have written it down and got it working again. Thank you. What do I do now for stackoverflow? I tried up-voting you but it didn't allow me because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Keep exploring stackoverflow, and try helping people ;)